# Flutter caching Firestore record on mobile app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, sharedpreferences

I'm creating an app using Flutter &  Google's Firestore database. The app uses Firebase's authentications so once authenticated I grab the user document from the database and store it using **[shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)** plugin. I'm doing this to reduce the number of calls to Firestore as I'm using the document in many screens.

The problem is, I'm updating the document in many places and I have to remember to update the local cached version of the document which is not ideal.

My question is does Firestore have built-in caching feature so that if the document hasn't changed it doesn't hit the database?

If Firestore doesn't have any caching feature, what's the best way of managing document changes in one place?

Any code reference or plugins would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I already used Firestore I have a few tips: other than using StreamProvider for actively listen to firestore document changes, I'd recommend building your own system for writing/flushing data. Also, try to use batches and transactions for writing, since it is all-or-none both for changes and for pricing.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore has offline persistence.  Take some time to read about it in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) and [this post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firestore-clients-to-cache-or-not-to-cache-or-both-8f66a239c329).

If that doesn't work for you, you will need to come up with something on your own that meets your needs.  A full discussion is too broad for Stack Overflow.